# Question about "taking Cartesian products"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is from Terry Tao's Introduction to Measure Theory Lemma 1.1.2.

I can show that for an interval $I$, the length of $I$ can be recovered using
$$|I|=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac1N\#\left(I\cap \frac1N\textbf{Z}\right)$$
where $\frac1N\textbf{Z}:=\left\lbrace\frac{n}{N}\mid n\in \textbf{Z}\right\rbrace$.

However, I do not understand the next step, where he writes that "taking Cartesian products, we see that
$$|B|=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac1{N^d}\#\left(I\cap \frac1N\textbf{Z}^d\right)$$
for any box $B$," where $B=I_1\times\cdots\times I_d$ of $d$ intervals (this is a Cartesian product).

I am confused because $|I|$ is just a real number, and $|B|$ was defined as $|B|=|I_1|\times\cdots\times |I_d|$, the product of real numbers. So it seems like we would just have $n$ limits multiplied together for $|B|$. I am not sure how the formula for $|B|$ is derived from the formula for $|I|$.

Comment: Well, $\frac1N\Bbb Z^d$ is the set of all points $(a_1/N,\ldots,a_d/N)$ with $a_1,\ldots,a_d$ integers.

Comment: How does that arise from the formula for the size of an interval?

Comment: $N$ is a number and $N^d$ is a number. $\# ( \ldots  )$ is the cardinality of a finite set, and thus is a number. So, in conclusion, the RHS is a function of $N$ and it makes sense to consider the limit for $N \to \infty$. If it exists it will be a number exactly as the LHS: $|B|$.

Comment: I agree that the formula does make sense - but I guess my question is how one can derive the formula for $|B|$ by "taking Cartesian products" of the formula for $|I|$.